# How can I tell which LEGO minifigure I found?

Tags: minifigure-identification

I found a mini-figure on the the ground by a recycling bin. I want to figure out what set/collection he belongs to but can't find anything other than how to tell what you're getting in a blind bag.

He's normal size for a mini-fig, not a shorty or anything.
He has a dark red pirate bandanna type hat with a "tail" hanging down his head.
His head is grey or grey-green with green eyebrow and cheek markings and pointy looking bottom teeth made to look protruding from his mouth.
His torso is a dark orange with a silver breastplate and brown straps on his back. Also there is a dark red belt. His arms are black and his hands are brown.
His pants are red but not dark red like his hat.

He's a mean looking guy and doesn't seem to match Pirates of the Caribbean or Lord of the Rings/Hobbit but looks like he would fit in with those sets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A picture would significantly help identification.  Also, your minifigure may in fact not be one figure, but a composition of different figures.  We are talking about LEGO after all.

Answer (score 14):

The torso is from [Lando Calrissian](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb1168c01).

[image: Lando Calrissian skiff guard torso]

The rest of the parts are from [Kithaba](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=sw397).

[image: Kithaba minifigure]

They both came in the 2012 [Desert Skiff Star Wars set](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=9496-1)

Comment: Thanks oddTodd, that looks exactly like him. Maybe someone was tossing old parts and he was just stuck together with what they had

Comment: That's an impressive bit of detective work!

Comment: @JustinCase to some people the point of Lego is that you can mix and match the pieces, and that's how they use it. Not everyone just buys it, assembles it according to the instructions, then displays it.